# How to simulate content overflow with react-testing-library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am using material-table along with material ui to create a spreadsheet application. One of the behaviours I have implemented is a maximum width on cells of 50px. If the contents of that cell are too big, it will default to an ellipsis at the end of the word (see Typography Material-UI component with noWrap prop enabled). If this cell is hovered, a popover will render, showing the full contents of the cell. It checks if the cell is overflowing by checking if scrollWidth > clientWidth, and if so, enables onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave behaviour for showing and hiding the pop up. This all works fine. My problem is, I am struggling to replicate this behaviour within a test written using jest/react-testing-library. When I call the react-testing render method, it does not output overflow behaviour, even with a very long value within the cell component. Is this because it is on virtually rendering as opposed to actually rendering within a browser? If  so, is there a way I can force the overflow behaviour? I have attached my current component, along with the calculate overflow function and current test.

```
const calculateOverflow = element => {
  return element ? element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth : false;
}
```

```
export default function OverflowCell(props) {
  const typeRef = useRef();
  const { value } = props;
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handlePopoverOpen = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handlePopoverClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const isOverflowing = calculateOverflow(typeRef.current);

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography
        ref={typeRef}
        aria-owns={open ? 'mouse-over-popover' : undefined}
        aria-haspopup={isOverflowing ? 'true' : 'false'}
        aria-label={isOverflowing ? 'overflowCell' : 'cell'}
        onMouseEnter={isOverflowing ? handlePopoverOpen : undefined}
        onMouseLeave={isOverflowing ? handlePopoverClose : undefined}
        className={classes.overFlowText}
        noWrap
      >
        {value}
      </Typography>
      {isOverflowing && (
        <Popover
          className={classes.popover}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.paper,
          }}
          open={open}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: 'bottom',
            horizontal: 'left',
          }}
          transformOrigin={{
            vertical: 'top',
            horizontal: 'left',
          }}
          onClose={handlePopoverClose}
          disableRestoreFocus
        >
          <Typography>{value}</Typography>
        </Popover>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
it('triggers popover when overflowing string is hovered', async () => {
  const cellValue = 'test value that is very longggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg';
  const divStyle = {
    'max-width': '10',
  };
  mockRowData[0].forname = cellValue;
  const { asFragment, getByLabelText } = render(
    <div style={divStyle}>
      <OverflowCell value={cellValue} />
    </div>,
  );
  const initialRender = asFragment();
  const overflowCell = getByLabelText('cell');
  Simulate.mouseEnter(overflowCell);
  await delay(500);
  expect(initialRender).toMatchDiffSnapshot(asFragment());
  Simulate.mouseLeave(overflowCell);
  await delay(500);
  expect(initialRender).toMatchSnapshot(asFragment());
});
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Were you ever able to get this working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-testing-library: Verify text truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72491509/react-testing-library-verify-text-truncation)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the unit test doesn't run in a real browser. So it doesn't execute the CSS and doesn't have scroll.