# react-testing-library: Verify text truncation

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, truncation

I have a component "Label" which has rudimentary truncation support:

```js
import "./styles.css";
export default function Label(props) {
  const className = props.truncate ? "truncate" : "";
  return <label className={className}>{props.children}</label>;
}
```

The `truncate` css class:

```css
.truncate {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-https-w2oug6) which demonstrates the component and it's `truncation` prop:

[image: screenshot of codesandbox output]

---

Now I'm at the point where I want to add some test coverage for the truncation feature.
I'm using react-testing-library, but **I'm not sure the best way to assert that the end of the text is not visible with truncation**.

Here is my attempt:

```js
const longText = 'START Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ac commodo massa END';
describe('Label', () => {
  it('displays long text', () => {
    render(<Label>{longText}</Label>);
    expect(screen.getByText(/^START/)).toBeInTheDocument(); // pass
    expect(screen.getByText(/END$/)).toBeInTheDocument(); // pass
  });
  it('displays long text with truncation', () => {
    render(<Label truncate={true}>{longText}</Label>);
    expect(screen.getByText(/^START/)).toBeInTheDocument(); // pass
    expect(screen.queryByText(/END$/)).not.toBeVisible(); // FAILURE
  });
});
```

The last `expect` is failing with:

```
Received element is visible:
    <label class="truncate" />
```

I understand that I could test for the presence of the class name, but our team feels that it's a poor practice to rely on that.

**Is there a best-practice way to test for text truncation?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a `screen.debug` right after the render with `truncate`, like this:

```js
render(<Label truncate={true}>{longText}</Label>);

screen.debug();
```

the output will be:

```html
<label class="truncate">
      START Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ac commodo massa END
</label>
```

As you can see the entire text is rendered and what makes the text visible/not visible is the css `overflow` property.

Said that, I think the best approach here its just verify if the component has or hasn't the `overflow` property:

```js
expect(screen.getByText(/^START/)).toHaveStyle("overflow: hidden");
```